# Add class name to Json objects but only when needed with Gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to create a `TypeAdapter` that adds an attribute 'className' when the runtime type is not the same as the declarative type.

For example, I have the following classes:

```
public class TestData {
    private TestInterface testInterface;
    private TestImpl testImpl
    private Object testObject
    // getters/setters
}

public interface TestInterface {
}

public class TestImpl implements TestInterface {
    private String value
    // getter/setter
}
```

Now I want to serialize an instance of `TestData`, with:

- property `testInterface` set with an instance of `TestImpl` with `value="value1"`
- property `testImpl` set with an instance of `TestImpl` with `value="value2"`
- property `testObject` set with an instance of `TestImpl` with `value="value3"`

I would like to obtain the following Json document:

```
{
  "testInterface": {
    "className": "my.package.TestImpl", // The class name has been added because the type of the field testInterface is "TestInterface", and that does not match the type "TestImpl" of the value
    "instance": {
      "value": "value1"
    }
  },
  "testImpl": { // Nothing has been added because the declarative type of the field and the runtime type are the same (TestImpl).
    "value": "value2"
  },
  "testObject": {
    "className": "my.package.TestImpl", // Idem testInterface, but with types "Object" and "TestImpl"
    "instance": {
      "value": "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course I want to be able to unmarshall this document to the initial Java objects. The objects to serialize could be more complicated (for example with collections, maps, array or enum). Note that I don't need to have the className on collections, maps or array (For example, it's not important for me if the implementation of a `List` is `LinkedList` before marshalling and `ArrayList` after marshalling/unmarshalling, however the collection elements must be ok)

I didn't succeed to create such a `TypeAdapter`, because I didn't find a reliable way to retrieve the declarative type when the `TypeAdapter` is called. So I'm not able to determine if I have to add the class name or not. I'm a little disappointed to not achieve that, because it sounds to me like a common use case.

What I don't want:

- To register a `TypeAdapter` for each class/interface that needs to be enriched with the class name (I think that the `TypeAdapterFactory` could handle that)
- To add systematically the class name to all objects
- To use another Json library

Versions: Java 1.7, Gson 2.3.1

Any ideas are very welcomed :-)